# Does Encog provide an API for Decision Tree algorithms including ID3 and Q4.5?

Tags: java, encog

Does Encog provide an API for Decision Tree algorithms including ID3 and Q4.5?

If not, can you recommend other Java libraries that provide these functions?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you asking us? (Instead of looking it up).

Comment: Encog does not have decision tree support.  I suggest looking at Weka for that.

Comment: Thanks, Jeff!    Love your work!